# JAXB - ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1

Tags: jaxb

I am getting error :

```
GC 16192K->1983K(260160K), 0.0101954 secs]
avax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1 not
- with linked exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.ContextFactory_1_0_1]
       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:152)
       at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:258)
       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:372)
       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:337)
       at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:244)
```

I have added following jars:

jaxp-api.jar ,
jaxb-api.jar ,
jsr173_1.0_api.jar ,
jaxb-impl.jar ,
jaxb1-impl.jar ,
jaxb-libs.jar ,
jaxb-xjc.jar ,
jax-qname.jar ,
jaxrpc.jar ,
jaxrpc-api.jar , 
relaxngDatatype.jar

Can someone help me out what wrong with this code.

Note : The code works when I am running with sample code.

Comment: what environment is this in?  standalone java? which java version? appserver? if so, what version?

Comment: @ Skaffman - This is standalone program run by Unix shell script. I am using JDK1.6. I can see the file in the jaxb1-impl.jar. Still it give the error.

While running with a sample code in a java file, it runs perfectly.

Comment: Which version of JDK1.6?

Comment: The issue is resolved now by adding the jar file jaxb-api.jar. It was not there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When running with JDK 1.6 you do not need to include any JAXB 2 APIs on your classpath.  Are you trying to run a JAXB 1 code model?  If so, if this is not a legacy application I would suggest using JAXB 2 instead.

Comment: What's the diff between jaxp and jaxb.?

Answer (score 2):

Adding `this.getClass().getClassLoader()` in new Instance method should fix your problem...